# Como obtener el resultado variable de una función en una class A y usarlo en otra función en una class B en python

Tags: python, funciones, tkinter

Hice una función la cual toma 3 valores variables de una clase(A) y realiza una operación, quiero saber como puedo obtener el resultado de esa función y usarlo en una función de otra clase(B)

Esta es la función que esta en la clase(A):

```
def resultado_escalamiento2d(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.valores = []

    for i in args:
        self.valores.append(i)
    
    self.k = self.valores[2]
    self.valores.pop()

    self.Vector = np.array(self.valores)
    self.Vector_r = self.Vector*self.k
    self.Vector_r.tolist()
```

Aquí esta la función en la clase(B):

```
class Frame_r_e_2(tk.Frame):
def __init__(self, container, resultado_escalamiento2d ,controller, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(container, *args, **kwargs)
    self.configure(bg= "blue")

    resultado_escalamiento = ???
```

Answer (score 0):

Si entiendo bien tu pregunta, deseas obtener el resultado de la función **resultado_escalamiento2d** que se encuentra en la clase A y usarlo en la función **_*init***_ de la clase B.

Si es así, lo que debes hacer es crear una instancia de la clase A y llamar a su función resultado_escalamiento2d para obtener el resultado que deseas. Luego, puedes asignar el resultado a una variable y usarla en la función ****init**** de la clase B.

Por ejemplo:

```
# Primero creamos una instancia de la clase A
a = A()

# Llamamos a la función resultado_escalamiento2d de la instancia a y obtenemos el resultado
resultado_escalamiento = a.resultado_escalamiento2d(arg1, arg2, arg3)

# Luego creamos una instancia de la clase B y le pasamos el resultado como argumento
b = B(resultado_escalamiento)
```

Te recominendo repasar sobre instancias de POO.

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, te sugerimos revisar:  https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5450/cheatgpt-chatgpt-nos-ha-alcanzado-en-soes

Comment: Gracias por su sugerencia, pero fue redactado por mí.

Comment: Muchas gracias @CristianZúñiga